# Initialize struct from func that returns tuple

Tags: go

Ok so I have this:

```
handler.Mount(subRouter, routes.PersonInjection{PeopleById: models.PersonInit()})
```

PersonInit looks like:

```
func PersonInit() (Map,Map) {

    peopleById["1"] = Model{ID: 1, Handle: "alex", Firstname: "Alex", Lastname: "Chaz", Email: "alex@example.com", Password:"foo"}
    peopleById["2"] = Model{ID: 2, Handle: "jason",Firstname: "Jason", Lastname: "Statham", Email: "jason@example.com", Password:"foo"}
    peopleByHandle["alex"] = peopleById["1"]
    peopleByHandle["jason"] = peopleById["2"]

    return peopleById, peopleByHandle
}
```

the Map type is just `Map[string]someStruct{}`

and `PersonInjection{}` looks like:

```
type PersonInjection struct {
    PeopleById, PeopleByHandle person.Map
}
```

so I am looking to do something like:

```
handler.Mount(subRouter, routes.PersonInjection{PeopleById,PersonByHandle: models.PersonInit()...})
```

ummm anyone know how to do something like that?

for now I just have:

```
    by_id, by_handle := models.PersonInit()
    handler.Mount(subRouter, routes.PersonInjection{PeopleById: by_id, PeopleByHandle:by_handle})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no construction in Go which would help to make this one-liner. I think, what you have now is OK, except the [underscores in the variable names](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps).

Personally, I would add even more lines for the sake of readability:

```
var personInj routes.PersonInjection
personInj.PeopleById, personInj.PeopleByHandle = models.PersonInit()
handler.Mount(subRouter, personInj)
```